# Android Virtual Device on Windows 10 - Endless "VCPU shutdown request" - doesn't launch

Tags: android, windows, x86, android-virtual-device, haxm

My x86 AVDs never load. I've searched all over for a solution but haven't seen a solution that has worked for me.

**Configuration**

- OS: Windows 10 Home
- RAM: 12 GB
- CPU: Intel Core i5-7200
- CPU Supports VT-x, EM64T,and XD Bit as required by HAXM (per Intel specs)
- HAXM version: 6.0.4
- Android Studio version: 2.2
- Bios: Insyde F.21
- Bios config: Virtualization Technology enabled.

**Steps**
 1. In Android Studio, launch Android Virtual Device Manager.
 2. Create Nexus 5 API 24 AVD with all default settings.
 3. Launch the AVD.

Results:
AVD window displays. 
No "Android" text appears.
Android Run screen initially displays log entries that look positive, but then shows many instances of "VCPU shutdown request".
This goes on indefinitely, for hours if I leave it.
Virtual device stays "black" forever.

Starting few log entries:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_24
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=00748cea EBX=5ffadb60 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000000
ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00006d38
EIP=5ffb6921 EFL=00010082 [--S----] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
VCPU shutdown request
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
VCPU shutdown request
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
VCPU shutdown request
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
VCPU shutdown request
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
```

Stuff I've tried:

1. Hearing that Antivirus installed may prevent HAXM install from working: temporarily disabled AV, reinstalled HAXM, and tried running AVD with AV disabled - did not work.
2. Using an ARM-based AVD works, but I've read that an x86 AVD will work much faster, so I'm trying to get x86 to work.
3. Tried x86 and x86_64 AVDs to no avail.
4. Tried changing default HAXM setting of 2GB RAM to 4GB and 1GB. Same results.
5. Tried using AVDs with lower API levels such as 21. Same results.
6. Windows Event Viewer doesn't show any errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Once HAXM 6.0.5 was installed on my PC this solved the problem.

Comment: Note to  anyone else who sees this problem: **Android SDK Manger will tell you that it has installed HAXM 6.0.5 when that is not the case.** When SDK manager says it installed an updated version of HAXM it has only downloaded it to your Android SDK's **extras/intel** folder. After this I ran the SDK's **tools/emulator-check.exe** which revealed HAXM 6.0.4 was still installed. I then executed the **intelhaxm-android.exe** in the intel/extras folder. **Then AVDs launched with HAXM and without issue. Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a bug in current versions of HAXM.

The new HAXM 6.0.5 fixes this:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=226174#c51

Comment: a dupe answer from user Tomas

Comment: Yes, I was agreeing with Tomas. I posted because a preview version of the fix was uploaded today

Answer (score 8):

Seems to be an issue with the 7th gen processors on windows. Still trying to figure this one out.

**UPDATE:** Confirmed to be a HAXM issue on Kaby Lake, nothing we can do until we get an HAXM update from Intel. Either use the ARM image or ad the switch -accel off -verbose to the x86/x64 image....neither are desirable but will do the trick until we get a fix. You can also use an android device but that can be frustrating too.

Comment: For what its worth, I think the 7th gen is not the only one which has this problem. I am the proud owner of an i5 760 (1st gen?) and I am having this issue described here. Adding the -accel off switch seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue by one week, and here is the solution I've found:

**Operating system:** Windows 10
**HAXM version:** 7.5.1

**Solution:**
Disable **HP Sure Click** then restart your computer

Comment: I do not know why, but it did help me.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in HAXM. Intel is working on it

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=226174

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Android Studio
2. Click on configure from right bottom Go to AVD Manager
3. Click on down arrow in actions
4. Click on Cold boot now

Comment: this does not work