# Cannot launch AVD in emulator. VCPU shutdown request

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, haxm

Running on a kaby lake 7500u, virtualization enabled, hyperthreading disabled.

Re-installed android studio 2.2, HAXM 6.0.4 installed.

I have a hunch this may be an issue with kaby lake processors, as [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865230/android-virtual-device-on-windows-10-endless-vcpu-shutdown-request-doesnt/39866477#39866477) is experiencing the same issue as me and happens to be using an i5 7200.

Simple hello world app will not emulate. Following error code generated:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
VCPU shutdown request
VCPU shutdown request
VCPU shutdown request
VCPU shutdown request
VCPU shutdown request
VCPU shutdown request
VCPU shutdown request
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=00748cea EBX=5ffadb60 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000000
VCPU shutdown request
VCPU shutdown request
VCPU shutdown request
VCPU shutdown request
VCPU shutdown request
ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00006d38
EIP=5ffb6921 EFL=00010082 [--S----] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
```

Comment: Use Genymotion instead, it loads faster than AVD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have exact the same issue with my notebook running a kaby lake 7500u.
The problem most probabbly comes from HAXM.

The only way I managed  to get it working is by booting into ubuntu. (Not really a solution for most people) Kaby Lake 7500u with Ubuntu/KVM works as expected.

Update: It is a bug in HAXM. Intel is working on it

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=226174

Comment: to solve the issue, i had to recreate the AVD from scratch and it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed a bug with HAXM and Intel's 7th generation processors.

The new HAXM 6.0.5 fixes this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=226174#c51

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem. The only solution I could find was to use an android emulator called [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/). Note that Bluestacks must be running before android studio starts in order for it to show up in the virtual machine list when running your app.

Hope this helps