# emulator pie 9 Failed

Tags: android, emulation

**ERRORS:**

```
Emulator: Failed to sync vcpu reg

Emulator: C:\Users\user\android-sdks\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot
```

I installed Android Studio and installed HAXM, also I turn off all virtual machines running. When I try to launch the emulator it gives me these errors. What could be the problem? Could it have something in the background virtual machines that are working and I don't know, or could it be SDK path or something in the system environment variables?

[image]

[image]

Comment: run emulator from command line with 'emulator -verbose -avd name-of-image'. That should give more info about the problem

Answer (score 2):

I face same error msg.

After reading 'shtolik' advice, then I run command line.
(Thank you very much for your advice  ^^)

**C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator -verbose -avd Galaxy_Nexus_API_25**

and I found endless of **"VCPU shutdown request"**.
So I search in google.

**It seems there is bug** at
*'Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM)'*

For more details, please see this one.
[Android Virtual Device on Windows 10 - Endless "VCPU shutdown request" - doesn't launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865230/android-virtual-device-on-windows-10-endless-vcpu-shutdown-request-doesnt)