# The emulator process for AVD was killed

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, android-virtual-device

I just installed Android Studio and created a new AVD. However whenever I try to run it, I get an error message saying the process was killed, and the emulator will close. When running the emulator from cmd I get this message. What is going wrong?

```
emulator: Android emulator version 30.5.3.0 (build_id 7196367) (CL:N/A)
Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
emulator: WARNING: Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only.
added library vulkan-1.dll
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: INFO: GrpcServices.cpp:301: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
VCPU shutdown request
deleteSnapshot: for default_boot
```

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66665690/edit) you post to include where you are running your AVD (OS (Win/Mac/Linux), hardware (real or virtual), and CPU specifications. Possibly related:[Android Virtual Device on Windows 10 - Endless “VCPU shutdown request” - doesn't launch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39865230/295004)

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have enough space in c: drive - Minimum has 20GB free space
2. If you have already created AVD then go to following location in your windows machine, from command line enter "`emulator -list-avds`".

   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator -list-avds
   Pixel_2_API_29
3. Enter `emulator @Pixel_2_API_29`

   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator @Pixel_2_API_29
4. You can see emulator launching.

**It worked for me** - other result found in internet didn't worked for me.